# SQL Injection and static SQL

Tags: sql, sql-injection

Can someone please explain if the below type of queries are candidate for SQL Injection -

```
String code =StaticClass.getCode();
sql.append(" code = " + code);
```

And

SQL like

```
sql.append(" Code ='xyz'");
```

Thanks,
Tweety

Comment: Start here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: SQL Injection vulnerabilities occur whenever text entered by a user can form part of a SQL String.  You should never concatenate user entered strings into your SQL, you should ***always*** use parameterisation / prepared statements to include user defined values in your SQL.

Comment: Check out http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1):

Just imagine your "xyz" comes directly from a user's input.

Now imagine, the user would type in

```
x'; DROP TABLE User; --
```

And you concatenate something like

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Code='xyz'
```

But you would get

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE Code='x'; DROP TABLE User; --'
```

See what I mean?

### Learn to use parameters!

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can be, depending on where the value of the *code* variable is coming from (i.e. user input).

You can avoid SQL injection though by using queries with parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response.

They are not being input from the Web UI. They are being directly taken from a  variable having some value in the code itself. In this case, it is no more a sql injection attack category..right?

Comment: Please copy these lines into a comment - either below your question or below the appropriate answer. If this is a real enhancement you should use the edit option below the question to edit into the question's text. And after this you should delete both your answers - as they are no answers...

Answer (score 0):

To understand it correctly, if it is being input from the interface, there is a risk of sql injection where as a constant in the code would not effect it..right?

Comment: You should reflect on answers either by adding a comment or by editing your question. Posting an answer would generate noise for future visitors.